# Each solution of ODE approaches constant given inequality

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

given $x'(t)=f(x,t)$, if $|f(x,t)|\leq A(t)|x|$ and $\int_a^\infty A(s)ds=C\neq\infty$ each solution of IC approaches a constant value.

Approach:
Let $x(T)=x_0$

integrating $x'(t)=f(x,t)$ over $t$ in [T; $\infty)\implies \lim\limits_{t\to\infty}x(t)-x_0=\int_{T}^{\infty}f(x,s)ds$
$\lim\limits_{t\to\infty}x(t)=x_0+\int_{T}^{\infty}f(x,s)ds$

$\lim\limits_{t\to\infty}x(t)\leq |x_0|+|\int_{T}^{\infty}f(x,s)ds|\\ \leq |x_0|+\int_{T}^{\infty}|f(x,s)|ds\\ \leq|x_0|+\int_{T}^{\infty}A(s)|x|ds$

from condition on $A(s)$ can conclude that
$\lim\limits_{t\to\infty}x(t)<\infty$

but does it exist? function x may have no limit (like $\sin x$)

Correct me if im wrong

P.S. was also thinking about more general condition what will happen if $|f(x,t)-f(y,t)|\leq A(t)|x-y|$ if, suppose two different x,y solutions of ODE with different IC's, must these solutions converge to different values? Using the same approach led to:

$x-y\leq|x-y|\leq|x_0-y_0|+\int_{T}^\infty A(s)|x-y|ds<\infty$ but again
If I suppose the contrary that two different solutions converge to the same constant their difference at infinity must be $=0$ but it I'm stuck with applying limit to make use of condition on $A(t)$ to inequality above (just as in the special case checking one solution converging to constant).

Proof after hint of Lutz Lehmann

$x'(t)=f(x,t)\leq |f(x,t)|\leq A(t)|x|\\ |x'(t)|\leq A(t)|x|\\$ Applying Gronwalls inequality $x'\leq f(x,t)x\implies x\leq x_0 e^{\int_\tau^{\infty}f(s)ds}$

$$|x(t)| \leq |x_0| e^{\int_{\tau}^{\infty} A(s)ds}$$

Due to $\int_{\tau}^{\infty} A(s)ds=C<\infty$, means function $x(t)$ is bounded from both sides by the constant factor $e^{\int_{\tau}^{\infty} A(s)ds}$ mentioned above.

However question still remains: what happens when $t\to \infty$ with $x(t)$ as it is bounded from both sides due to derivation, but may oscillate at infinity.

Comment: First apply the Grönwall lemma to get that $x$ is bounded. With the same idea you can then also perhaps show a Cauchy sequence property.

Comment: Concerning your general condition: Consider the IVP $x'(t)=x(t)/(1+t^2)$, $x(0)=x_0$. Here $x(t) \to x_0 \exp(\pi/2)$ $(t \to \infty)$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann so ended up having $A\leq x(t)\leq B$, what to do with oscillatory possibility of x at $\infty$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Grönwall's lemma, you get
$$
|x'(t)|=|f(t,x(t))|\le A(t)|x(t)|\implies |x(t)|\le |x(0)|\exp\left(\int_0^tA(s)\,ds\right)\le |x(0)|e^\alpha
$$
if $\alpha=\int_0^\infty A(s)\,ds$. Now apply the Picard equation again
$$
|x(t)-x(t_0)|\le \int_{t_0}^tA(s)|x(0)|e^\alpha\,ds
$$
so that by setting $t_0$ sufficiently large, the right side can be made arbitrarily small. This is the condition for a Cauchy sequence for any discretization to a sequence of time points. Thus the limit exists.